# Functional testing of Emacs macro/elisp

Tags: emacs, macros, automated-tests

I'm tinkering with an Emacs add-on, which started out as a few simple macros but as always grows to a more complete, robust and complicated elisp implementation.

I started to feel that I wanted functional automatic tests for this functionality. Basically the "test suite" would copy some files to /tmp run a series of user level menu entries and key-bound functions with user input, then save the files and compare the output to some expected result.

Copying and comparing is no problem ;-), but the rest?

How can I drive emacs in a fashion that could enable automatic testing from a user perspective?

(Running headless would be a bonus. EDIT: found `--batch`  and `--script`)

Comment: See also [ERT](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/ert.html).

Comment: ERT looks real nice, I'll certainly look into that too, but not exactly what I was looking for right now.